# Missing module kubernetes.dynamic on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that uses the Python `kubernetes` module to perform some operations on elements in a Kubernetes cluster. I tested the playbook on a test cluster and now am trying to run it on a "real" cluster. I'm getting an error when attempting to use the module in the playbook.

**Note**: Ansible is **not** installed on the Kubernetes cluster nodes. Instead, we run a docker image that has Ansible tools installed. We run the playbook in this container and instruct it to operate on a cluster's nodes.

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_info_payload_qhfwi_iq/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_info_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 122, in <module>
    from kubernetes.dynamic.resource import ResourceInstance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes.dynamic'
fatal: [arc-master-1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "error": "No module named 'kubernetes.dynamic'",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null,
            "api_version": "v1",
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "context": null,
            "field_selectors": [],
            "host": null,
            "impersonate_groups": null,
            "impersonate_user": null,
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "kubeconfig": "/home/master/.kube/config",
            "label_selectors": [],
            "name": "kube-proxy",
            "namespace": "kube-system",
            "no_proxy": null,
            "password": null,
            "persist_config": null,
            "proxy": null,
            "proxy_headers": null,
            "username": null,
            "validate_certs": null,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_condition": null,
            "wait_sleep": 5,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (kubernetes) on arc-master-1's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

I have a prior task that installs the `kubernetes` module and that succeeds.

Here is the docker run command:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -e ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/data/ansible.cfg -e K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG=/home/master/.kube/config -v "C:\Users\jgagnon\devops\ansible":/data cytopia/ansible:latest-tools ansible-playbook /data/playbook-arc-prometheus.yaml
```

Here is one of the playbook tasks that fails:

```
- name: "Get kube-proxy ConfigMap"
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: kube-proxy
    namespace: kube-system
    kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('env', 'K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG') }}"
  register: kube_proxy_data
```

K8s cluster node details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Python: 3.8.10
Pip: 20.0.2
```

Results from running `pip list` on a *K8s node*:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
attrs                  19.3.0
Automat                0.8.0
blinker                1.4
cachetools             5.3.0
certifi                2019.11.28
chardet                3.0.4
Click                  7.0
cloud-init             22.4.2
colorama               0.4.3
command-not-found      0.3
configobj              5.0.6
constantly             15.1.0
cryptography           2.8
dbus-python            1.2.16
distro                 1.4.0
distro-info            0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints            0.3
google-auth            2.16.0
gpg                    1.13.1-unknown
httplib2               0.14.0
hyperlink              19.0.0
idna                   2.8
importlib-metadata     1.5.0
incremental            16.10.1
Jinja2                 2.10.1
jsonpatch              1.22
jsonpointer            2.0
jsonschema             3.2.0
keyring                18.0.1
kubernetes             25.3.0
language-selector      0.1
launchpadlib           1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient     0.14.2
lazr.uri               1.0.3
MarkupSafe             1.1.0
more-itertools         4.2.0
netifaces              0.10.4
oauthlib               3.1.0
pexpect                4.6.0
pip                    20.0.2
pyasn1                 0.4.2
pyasn1-modules         0.2.1
pycrypto               2.6.1
PyGObject              3.36.0
PyHamcrest             1.9.0
PyJWT                  1.7.1
pymacaroons            0.13.0
PyNaCl                 1.3.0
pyOpenSSL              19.0.0
pyrsistent             0.15.5
pyserial               3.4
python-apt             2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.8
python-dateutil        2.8.2
python-debian          0.1.36ubuntu1
PyYAML                 6.0
requests               2.22.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.1
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0
rsa                    4.9
SecretStorage          2.3.1
service-identity       18.1.0
setuptools             45.2.0
simplejson             3.16.0
six                    1.14.0
sos                    4.4
ssh-import-id          5.10
systemd-python         234
Twisted                18.9.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools 27.12
ufw                    0.36
unattended-upgrades    0.1
urllib3                1.25.8
wadllib                1.3.3
websocket-client       1.4.2
wheel                  0.34.2
zipp                   1.0.0
zope.interface         4.7.1
```

What is the problem? What is `kubernetes.dynamic` and why is it apparently not installed?

For what it's worth, the node details of the test cluster (which succeeds) is nearly identical. If anything, it is using an older Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. The python and pip versions are identical on both clusters.

Comment: I don't see ansible in you `pip list`, meaning you probably installed it via the package manager and are probably in an old, unmaintained version. What is your version of ansible?

Comment: Ansible is not installed on the n8s nodes. Instead, we run a docker image with Ansible that then operates on the cluster nodes.

Comment: The Ansible version:

bash-5.1# ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.1]
  config file = /play-config/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.9 (main, Dec 10 2022, 13:54:12) [GCC 11.2.1 20220219] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True

Comment: Using ansible to interact with kubernetes cluster you would need following python packages ansible, ansible-core & openshift.  are you using operator image to perform ansible based deployment?

Comment: Do these modules need to be installed in the Ansible Docker image, or on the cluster nodes?

Comment: They need to be installed on the host on which the anisble *tasks* are executing. If the tasks are targeting the cluster nodes, then the modules need to be installed there. If the tasks are targeting the Docker image (which is likely), then you need to install the modules in the Docker image.

Comment: I am assuming the `kubernetes` module tasks are running on K8s cluster nodes and therefore, need to be installed there. That is indeed where I'm installing it. The problem is that something appears to be missing from the installation.